# Ionic view - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: http, ionic-framework, cors, rails-api, ionic-view

I have seen this question being asked before but the answers haven't helped me.

I have ionic mobile app that makes use of a Rails 5.2 api that i built myself.
I'm having trouble geting a PUT request to go thru. 
I'm hitting this error.

```
Failed to load https://votingapi.herokuapp.com/api/v1/something: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have made GET request to the API and no problems with that. 
Managed to fix the problem in ionic serve --lab by enabling `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *`  plugin to chrome but the problem is still in the Ionic view.

Any thoughts?

Gemfile

```
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'
```

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
                 headers: :any,
                 methods: %w[:get :post :put :delete],
                 expose: %w[access-token expiry token-type uid client],
                 max_age: 0
      end
```

Request on ionic

```
update(id, result){
    let headers = new Headers();
    let body = JSON.stringify({vote: result})
    headers.append("Accept" , 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.put(`${this.apiUrl}/${id}`, body, options)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Preflight request is a http options request iirc. So you have to add it to the methods. Try this

```
methods: %w[:get :post :put :options :delete],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

So we found a solution to this problem.

This is the change we did:

```
%w[:get :post :put :delete :options] => %i[get post put delete options]
```

Checkout: https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview

They switched to this at some point on the ionic framework, and it says somewhere there that this enforces proper CORS settings compared to the previous one. So if the backend doesn’t setup cors rules appropriately it will not work
now.

we need an array of symbols for that config, and what we had was generating an array of strings

```
%w[:get :post :put :delete :options] returns [":get", ":post", ":put", ":delete", ":options"]
```

and

```
%i[get post put delete options] returns [:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options]
```

Hopefully this can someone :)